# Operation to extract values of an interval of a polynomial?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

A polynomial is normally defined on the interval $[-\infty,+\infty]$. I wonder if, given a polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{i}x^{i}$, there is a way or to be more precise - an operation - that does let me extract values of the polynomial on an interval $[a,b]$. The values on the intervals $[-\infty,a]$ and $[b,\infty]$ should then be zero.

So lets say I've got the polynomial $2x^2+7x+6$ and I want just the graph of the function on the interval $[-1,0]$. Is there a operation that does that?

Thanks for any responses!

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If you only want to graph the function on the interval $[-1, 0]$, why don't you just do it?

Comment: I think the problem here is to describe the endpoints of $f((a,b))$ when $f$ is a polynomial. If $f$ has no stationary points in $(a,b)$, the endpoints of such range are $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, but in general there is no simple algorithm for solving such problem - you have to compute a discriminant or locate the stationary points by studying $f'(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One usually denotes this function by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 &;\text{if }x<a \\ \sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i &;\text{if }a\leq x\leq b \\ 0 &;\text{if } x>b.\end{cases}$$
Equivalently, you can use the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)
$$\chi_{[a,b]}(x)=\begin{cases} 1 &;x\in[a,b]\\ 0 &;\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
and then
$$f(x)=\chi_{[a,b]}(x) \sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i.$$

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if I could do this multiplying the polynomial by a heaviside step fuction.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the characteristic function $\chi$ of the interval $[a,b]$. It is such that $\chi(x)=1$ if $x\in [a,b]$ and $0$ otherwise. The function you're looking for is then
$$\chi(x)\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i$$